# Exception because of stale OneToMany relation when merging

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My entities are like:

```
class Parent {
   @Id
   long id;

   @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name="childId", insertable=false, updatable=false)
   Set<Child> children = new HashSet<Child>();
}

class Child {
   @Id
   long id;
}
```

I have a Parent entity with some Child loaded in thread A. In thread B, the code deletes Child that belongs to Parent entity in thread A. As a result, thread A encounter javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException when calling entityManager.merge() because field children contains stale data that has been deleted.

How should I handle this concurrent situation?

Comment: some links: [locking](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html),
[relationship owner and optimistic locking](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=927463&sid=2987cbfd97002d4d35646a104245c6c6) and [its JPA impl](http://amitstechblog.wordpress.com/2011/10/16/inverse-relationship-in-hibernate-and-jpa/)